# Jquery - selecting parents with a data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute, parents

I am trying to select a parent which HAS an attribute of datalink

```
var url = $(e.target).parents(['data-link']).addClass('selected');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
.parents('[data-link]') //<-- string denoting attribute
```

not

```
.parents(['data-link']) //<-- array containing string
```